# How to get `length` of Matlab GUI popup menu strings

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I want to get how many strings exist in the popup menu, how can this be done? This code that I have written does not seem to work.

```
length(get(handles.popupMenu,'Value'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Value` is the index of the currently selected item in the menu so it will only ever be a scalar. You instead want to check the length of the `String` property which contains a cell array of strings (one for each item).

```
nOptions = numel(get(handles.popupMenu, 'String'));
```